# Printing a series of numbers

Tags: java, loops, count

I am trying to print all the values from 1-20 in the values column.

All the square values of i as it increases in the square value and the cube value.

When I run my code, there is an error. Can someone please help me !!

```
package jsquaresandcubes;
public class JSquaresandCubes {


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            //display a title at top 
            System.out.printf ("Value        Square          Cube\n");

            //display numbers 1-20 
            for(int i=0; i<20; i++){
              int square = i * i;
              int cube = i * i * i;

              System.out.printf("%4d%c  %8.6f   %8.6f   %8.6f\n", 
                   i,  square, cube);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: "When I run my code, there is an error." is not a description of your problem.

Comment: What error are you getting? Also its probably the fact you expect 5 inputs in the string `%4d%c  %8.6f   %8.6f   %8.6f` and only 3 inputs to replace them.

Comment: See [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/5699679). Also, `%d` is the format specifier for `int`, not `%f`. Furthermore, your format String has 5 of `%f/%c/%d` and you only provide 3 parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //display a title at top 
    System.out.printf ("Value        Square          Cube\n");

    //display numbers 1-20 
    for(int i=0; i<20; i++){
      int square = i * i;
      int cube = i * i * i;

      System.out.printf("%-14d %-14d %-14d \n", 
           i,  square, cube);
    }
}
```